# android linearlayout has no known child tags Error

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have following xml in my android app:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
         android:background="@drawable/msngr"
>
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/logo" />
     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Upto this code is fine, but i am not able to add any other components like TextView,Edittext in this.

I am not getting any autosuggest for it and viewing in redline that:

```
<linearlayout> has no known child tags
```

How can i components in linear layout?

plz help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in ScrollView you can only add one Child View... It can't add any other view in it... Because ScrollView host only one child view...

also remove space from Linear Layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

because space not allowed......

```
and if you want to add child view then add it to only LInear Layout
```

Comment: what can be alternative on this? I want to take whole login thing in scrollview

Comment: for that you have take one Linear Layout in SCroll view which orientation will be Vertical and in that Linear layout you can take another child linear layout and add all controls which you want to add according to your requirement.